# Rails Dynamic Role-Based Authorization plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, ruby-on-rails-plugins

There are a lot of role-based authorization plugins out there. They work great when you know in advance what the roles are going to be. For example, if I know I'm going to have administrators, super_users, and not_so_super_users.

What I really want is to be able to create custom roles and assign that role to a user. At this point, I am simply wanting to block access to controllers / actions based on a user's custom role. Roles will consist of permissions.

For example, Jane Doe can add and view widgets, but she can't delete or edit them. John Doe can add, view, and edit. The Boss can add, view, edit, and delete. I want to be able to check if the user is authorized to access a controller / action in one line:

```
user.is_authorized?
```

is_authorized (or whatever it is called) should be intelligent enough to determine if the user is authorized based on their assigned role and that role's permission set.

Am I making sense? Is there anything out there that does this?

Comment: What about if you did user.is_authorized_to?(:add, @widget) .... that way that method could check based on rules you define. It's all custom, but looks readable

Comment: I really like the syntax of that, but you need to know the keywords for your first parameter (probably one per CRUD operation). I want to apply this logic to any action, including actions that interact with zero or many different models. In the controller, you could use before_filter to check if user.is_authorized? and redirect if necessary. is_authorized? could possibly check against a list of routes that the user is able to access. Just brainstorming here... What I'm really looking for is role-based route authorization, not role-based model authorization

Comment: Not sure there's much logic that would warrant a plugin. You have to map each controller action to a role somehow, that's where the meat is.

Answer (score 0):

Please try plugin acl9 for role based application.

[acl9](http://github.com/be9/acl9)

Comment: This looks like a decent plugin, but not quite what I'm looking for. I'm looking for something a bit simpler and also that could easily have views setup so that the user can create and assign roles.

Answer (score 0):

I would use declarative_authorization and simply create multiple roles for each function.

So have a specific role to edit,update,create,destroy a widget (4 different roles).

Then just associate the user with multiple roles, saves reimplementing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try canard https://rubygems.org/gems/canard it uses all the dynamic authorisation of cancan and adds roles to it. I wrote it specifically to solve this problem.